# C# - Combine two or more Classes for Json Serialization

Tags: c#, json

How can I combine two or more Classes for Json Serialization c# ?

I need to combine two class objects into one Json Output. Is it possible? 
Please advise...

Both class objects are filled by returning data from 2 diffrent storedprocedures.

Comment: What is your Json looks like ? What is your Classes looks like ? What have you try ?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811301/merge-two-objects-during-serialization-using-json-net there is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a Super class as in the following example (OutputData) and Add your child classes to it 

    public class OutputData
    {
        public OutputData()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
        public JsonData1 jsondata1 = new JsonData1();
        public JsonData2 jsondata2 = new JsonData2();
    }



    public void AddJsonData ()
    {
    // And in the Function which addes data to the JsonData1 and JsonData2 Add the folloiwng lines.

        JsonData1  jsondata1  = new JsonData1 ();
        JsonData1  jsondata2  = new JsonData2 ();
        OutputData outputdata = new OutputData();
        string JsonOutput = "";

    //Assign the Json data classes with data to the SuperClass object
        outputdata.JsonData1 = jsondata1 ;
        outputdata.JsonData2 = jsondata2 ;  

    // Add some Data to your Json Classes

        jsondata1.UserName= "ABCD";
        jsondata1.UserID= "AB12";

        jsondata2.Country = "OOO";
        jsondata2.City = "CCC";

        //Create an object of the Json convert Class

        ConvertOutput convertoutput = new ConvertOutput();

        try
        {
             JsonOutput = convertoutput.ConvertObjecttoJSON(outputdata);
        }
    }

public class ConvertOutput
{

    public string ConvertObjecttoJSON(object clsobj)
    {

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
              new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(clsobj); 
        //Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        return jsonString;
    }

}


// And in your Angular JS, Ajax/JavaScript Refer the output object with Each Classnames. 

//if you check the Json output text file you can see how each class objects are added to it.

    success: function (data) {                

            var msg1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            var msg = JSON.parse(msg1);

        var strName = msg.jsondata1.UserName;
        var strCountry = msg.jsondata2.Country;

    });

// Happy Coding Everyone, hope this helps. 
// Cheeers
// C J
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can make one output from two classes. But you can simply create a new class with those 2 in it. Like following example:

```
public class MyHelperClass
{
    public MyFirstClass FirstObject { get; set; }
    public MySecondClass SecondObject { get; set; }
}
```

And then just create a new MyHelperClass-Object and set your two objects and serialize/deserialize the MyHelperClass-Object.

**Edit**

When your objects are from the same base-class you can just create an Array or a List and then serialize/deserialize that list-object

Comment: Great idea Joehl, I have developed it around your idea, slight changes though. But its certainly working!!