# How to serialize field of type class as main object fields with NewtonSoft json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

Assume that i have these classes:

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
    public int id;
}

public class A : BaseEntity
{
    public int aField;
    public C c;
}

public class B : BaseEntity
{
    public string bField;
    public C c;
}

public class C : BaseEntity
{
    public string cField;
}
```

Now, i want to use JSON.Net `JsonConverter` annotation to serialize `C` as below when i want to load `A` or `B` objects. for example something like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverterCustomImpl))]
public class C
{
    public string cField;
}
```

and the result of serialized `A` or `B` objects should be like this:

```
// A object
{
   id: 0,
   aField: 0,
   cField: ''
}

// B object
{
   id: 0,
   bField: 0,
   cField: ''
}
```

I dont know how shoud=ld i implement the `JsonConverterCustomImpl` class.

**UPDATE**

i'm used from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811301/merge-two-objects-during-serialization-using-json-net#answer-19811557) answer, also defined `FlattenJsonConverter` class and set it to JsonAnnotation of `A` and `B`, but when i run the project, thi exception was thrown:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll**

[image]

**UPDATE**

See this below diagram, The `C` class is `Attachment` in my application and many of models may be contains that.
The `Attachment` class have a `byte[] fileContent` field that contains the uploaded file content. So i want to serialize this class as flatten with container class to have a easily access to `fileContent` in `UI` side.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719509/json-net-throws-stackoverflowexception-when-using-jsonconvert) way to Serialize `C` class flatten, but it throws exception when using from `JsonConverter` in annotation.

**NOTE**
I'm serialize `fileContent` as a `base64 string`.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your problem a little, please?  1) Why do you need a converter on `C`?  2) Is your difficulty in serialization, or deserialization?  3) What json are you trying to create for `C`?

Comment: @dbc updated question, please check.

Comment: Why not simply add a `virtual byte[] fileContent { get { return null; } }` in the base class, then override that in `C`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to simply serialize an object with Newtonsoft.Json
(http://blog.bitlinkit.com/custom-json/)

```
public ActionResult hello()
{
    dynamic d = new JObject();
    d.MetricId = 11;
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
    return Content(json,"JSon");
}
```

no need to implement the `JsonConverterCustomImpl` class

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you could achieve the result by using inheritance instead of composition.
The code would look like this:

```
public class A : C
{
   public int aField;
}

public class B : C
{
   public string bField;
}
```

In case there are constraints which rule out this solution, consider editing the  question.

Comment: i can not do this because each `A` and `B` are extended from class named `BaseEntity `, and `A` and `B` classes are the Entity classes that i'm used in data layer.