# Json.NET different json structure, based on enum value

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I need to convert my class to JSON and I use Json.NET. But I can have different JSON structures, like:

```
{
    name: "Name",
    type: "simple1",
    value: 100
};
```

or

```
{
    name: "Name",
    type: {
        optional1: {
            setting1: "s1",
            setting2: "s2",
            ///etc.
    },
    value: 100
};
```

My C# code is:

```
public class Configuration
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public MyEnumTypes Type { get; set; }

    public OptionalType TypeAdditionalData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeType()
    {
        OptionalSettingsAttribute optionalSettingsAttr = this.Type.GetAttributeOfType<OptionalSettingsAttribute>();
        return optionalSettingsAttr == null;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeTypeAdditionalData()
    {
        OptionalSettingsAttribute optionalSettingsAttr = this.Type.GetAttributeOfType<OptionalSettingsAttribute>();
        return optionalSettingsAttr != null;
    }
}

public enum MyEnumTypes 
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "simple1")]
    Simple1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "simple2")]
    Simple2,

    [OptionalSettingsAttribute]
    [EnumMember(Value = "optional1")]
    Optional1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "optional2")]
    [OptionalSettingsAttribute]
    Optional2
}
```

My idea was when `Configuration.Type` - value hasn't attribute `OptionalSettingsAttribute` - to serialize it as `type: "simple1"`. Otherwise - to use `Configuration.Type` - value as type's value key (`type: { optional1: {} }`) and value in `Configuration.TypeAdditionalData` as `optional1` - value (like 2 simple JSON above).

I tried to create a custom Converter, like:

```
public class ConfigurationCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Configuration).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<Configuration>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //my changes here

        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
```

But when I add `[JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigurationCustomConverter))]` attribute to `Configuration` class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigurationCustomConverter))]
public class Configuration
```

and called `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configurationObj);` I received next error:

> Self referencing loop detected with type 'Configuration'. Path ''.

Do you have any ideas how to change my code to serialize my class to 2 different JSON structures?
**Note:** I  won't use the same class to deserialize the JSON.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `Self referencing loop detected` exception is that the [`WriteJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) method of your converter is calling itself recursively.  When you apply a converter to a type using `[JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigurationCustomConverter))]`, the `WriteJson()` method will **unconditionally replace** Json.NET's default implementation. Thus your inner call:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    //my changes here
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

would cause a stack overflow.  Json.NET notices this and instead throws the exception you see.  For more details, see [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719509/json-net-throws-stackoverflowexception-when-using-jsonconvert).  Setting `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` simply causes the infinite recursion to be skipped, leaving your object empty.

You have a few options to solve this problem:

1. You could manually write all property names and values other than `Type` and `TypeAdditionalData` then write out the custom `"type"` property last.   For instance:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigurationConverter))]
   public class Configuration
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public MyEnumTypes Type { get; set; }

       public OptionalType TypeAdditionalData { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
       public int Value { get; set; }
   }

   class ConfigurationConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       const string typeName = "type";

       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return typeof(Configuration).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
               return null;
           var config = (existingValue as Configuration ?? (Configuration)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());

           // Populate the regular property values.
           var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
           var type = obj.RemoveProperty(typeName);
           using (var subReader = obj.CreateReader())
               serializer.Populate(subReader, config);

           // Populate Type and OptionalType
           if (type is JValue) // Primitive value
           {
               config.Type = type.ToObject<MyEnumTypes>(serializer);
           }
           else
           {
               var dictionary = type.ToObject<Dictionary<MyEnumTypes, OptionalType>>(serializer);
               if (dictionary.Count > 0)
               {
                   config.Type = dictionary.Keys.First();
                   config.TypeAdditionalData = dictionary.Values.First();
               }
           }

           return config;
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var config = (Configuration)value;
           var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(config.GetType());
           writer.WriteStartObject();
           foreach (var property in contract.Properties
               .Where(p => p.Writable && (p.ShouldSerialize == null || p.ShouldSerialize(config)) && !p.Ignored))
           {
               if (property.UnderlyingName == "Type" || property.UnderlyingName == "TypeAdditionalData")
                   continue;
               var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(config);
               if (propertyValue == null && serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
                   continue;
               writer.WritePropertyName(property.PropertyName);
               serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
           }
           writer.WritePropertyName(typeName);
           if (config.Type.GetCustomAttributeOfEnum<OptionalSettingsAttribute>() == null)
           {
               serializer.Serialize(writer, config.Type);
           }
           else
           {
               var dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnumTypes, OptionalType>
               {
                   { config.Type, config.TypeAdditionalData },
               };
               serializer.Serialize(writer, dictionary);
           }
           writer.WriteEndObject();
       }
   }

   public class OptionalType
   {
       public string setting1 { get; set; }
   }

   public class OptionalSettingsAttribute : System.Attribute
   {
       public OptionalSettingsAttribute()
       {
       }
   }

   [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
   public enum MyEnumTypes
   {
       [EnumMember(Value = "simple1")]
       Simple1,

       [EnumMember(Value = "simple2")]
       Simple2,

       [OptionalSettingsAttribute]
       [EnumMember(Value = "optional1")]
       Optional1,

       [EnumMember(Value = "optional2")]
       [OptionalSettingsAttribute]
       Optional2
   }

   public static class EnumExtensions
   {
       public static TAttribute GetCustomAttributeOfEnum<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
           where TAttribute : System.Attribute
       {
           var type = value.GetType();
           var memInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
           return memInfo[0].GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
       }
   }

   public static class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static JToken RemoveProperty(this JObject obj, string name)
       {
           if (obj == null)
               return null;
           var property = obj.Property(name);
           if (property == null)
               return null;
           var value = property.Value;
           property.Remove();
           property.Value = null;
           return value;
       }
   }
   ```

   Notice I added `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` to your enum.  This ensures the type is always written as a string.

   Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9NisVT).
2. You could disable recursive calls to the converter via the technique shown in [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719509/json-net-throws-stackoverflowexception-when-using-jsonconvert), generate a default serialization, modify it as required, and write it out.
3. You could avoid the use of a converter entirely by marking `Type` and `TypeAdditionalData` as `[JsonIgnore]` and introducing an additional private property to serialize and deserialize `"type"`:

   ```
   public class Configuration
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [JsonIgnore]
       public MyEnumTypes Type { get; set; }

       [JsonIgnore]
       public OptionalType TypeAdditionalData { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("type")]
       JToken SerializedType
       {
           get
           {
               if (Type.GetCustomAttributeOfEnum<OptionalSettingsAttribute>() == null)
               {
                   return JToken.FromObject(Type);
               }
               else
               {
                   var dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnumTypes, OptionalType>
                   {
                       { Type, TypeAdditionalData },
                   };
                   return JToken.FromObject(dictionary);
               }
           }
           set
           {
               if (value == null || value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
               {
                   TypeAdditionalData = null;
                   Type = default(MyEnumTypes);
               }
               else if (value is JValue)
               {
                   Type = value.ToObject<MyEnumTypes>();
               }
               else
               {
                   var dictionary = value.ToObject<Dictionary<MyEnumTypes, OptionalType>>();
                   if (dictionary.Count > 0)
                   {
                       Type = dictionary.Keys.First();
                       TypeAdditionalData = dictionary.Values.First();
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
       public int Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @dbc a lot! I tried solution #3 and it is working for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to move past that error, you can configure your serialization to ignore the reference loop. This is done by using one of the `SerializaObject()` overloads.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configurationObj,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    { 
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the "Reference loop" error, but if `WriteJson` method has next code:
`public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }`
the serialized string is empty - nothing has converted. Is it correct? How I can use the default converter in my custom converter?

Thank you!

Comment: I have not run into the situation that you are describing and I am not next to my computer to investigate more. I will be on Monday. Hopefully someone else can help before then. Please update your question with progress you made with the information that I provided so the next person can help answer the full question.

Comment: Thank you! I used the solution #3 in @dbc - answer and it is working for me!