# Selectively use default JSON converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I use the following in my Web API project's `Startup.cs` to JSON-serialize Enums into strings:

```
// Configure JSON Serialization
var jsonSerializationSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
jsonSerializationSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
jsonSerializationSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

This is to avoid decorating every Enum property with `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`

Now, how can I selectively opt out of my global serialization setting for some Enum properties and use the default serializer that converts to integers?

Comment: Ideally you shall only decorate the required `properties` instead of the Global setting

Comment: Do you want to opt out for specific properties, or for specific enums?

Comment: @dcb For specific properties, probably by using an attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could add a dummy converter to the properties in question that does nothing:

```
public class NoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // Note - not called when attached directly via [JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then attach it to the property using [`[JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).  Having done so, the `JsonConverter` attribute's converter supersedes the globally specified converter, but since `CanRead` and `CanWrite` both return false no conversion is performed.  For collections of enums, you could use [`[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(NoConverter))]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm).

For instance, if you define the types:

```
public enum Foo { A, B, C }

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]
    public Foo FooAsInteger { get; set; }

    public Foo FooAsString { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
var root = new RootObject { FooAsInteger = Foo.B, FooAsString = Foo.B };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, new StringEnumConverter());

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Produces the output

```
{
  "FooAsInteger": 1,
  "FooAsString": "B"
}
```

Note that you can also apply `NoConverter` directly to the enum, if you want all occurrences of the enum in all data models to be serialized as an integer:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]
public enum FooAlwaysAsInteger { A, B, C }
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yxWN9i).