# How to use the NewtonSoft JsonConverterAttribute and JToken.FromObject() without calling the JsonConverter recursively

Tags: json.net, jsonconvert, jsonconverter

I have taken the code from [this example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and changed a few things:

1. remove the custom constructor and hardcode the `CanConvert` type.
2. removed the converter from the calls `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`
3. added a JsonConverter attribute to the Employee type

So I ended up with this console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee
            {
                FirstName = "James",
                Roles = new List<string> {"Admin"}
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Formatting.Indented);

            Console.WriteLine(json);

            Employee newEmployee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(newEmployee.FirstName);
        }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeysJsonConverter))]
    public class Employee
    {
        public string        FirstName { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Roles     { get; set; }
    }

    public class KeysJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

            if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                JObject o = (JObject)t;
                IList<string> propertyNames = o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                o.AddFirst(new JProperty("Keys", new JArray(propertyNames)));

                o.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(Employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the use of the attribute instead of explicitly specifying the converter when serializing and de-serializing has a side effect:
The assignment `JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);` now causes `WriteJson()` to be called recursively, resulting in a stack overflow!

It would really be nice to use the attribute rather than specifying converters everywhere the items are serialized/deserialized.

I am trying to add some generic type info while serializing/deserializing an interface, and I would like to reuse the default behavior of serialization for the most part. Is there any alternative way to do so without calling `JToken.FromObject()` or anything else that would cause the recursion loop?

Already tried calling `base.WriteJson()` on `JsonConverter` but it is an abstract method.

Comment: Take a look at [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using `[JsonConvert()]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: I did not find that one, so yes mine is a duplicate. Glad to find there are some answers as well, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.