# JSON serialization with custom mapping in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize/deserialize following classes into/from JSON:

```
public class Employee 
{
    string name;
    Position position;
}

public class Position 
{
    string positionName;
    int salary;
}
```

The tricky part is that I want to treat `Position` fields as `Employee` fields, so JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "positionName": "Manager",
    "salary" : 1000
}
```

How to achieve this using Json.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have either to deserialize it as anonymous object either (recommended ) implement a custom deserialization as stated here:

[Merge two objects during serialization using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811301/merge-two-objects-during-serialization-using-json-net)

Please let us know if there any more questions.

Here's an example (you can find it in the provided link):

```
public class FlattenJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
            return;
        }

        JObject o = (JObject)t;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        WriteJson(writer, o);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    private void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, JObject value)
    {
        foreach (var p in value.Properties())
        {
            if (p.Value is JObject)
                WriteJson(writer, (JObject)p.Value);
            else
                p.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
       object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true; // works for any type
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be grateful for an example.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Position p = new Position();
            p.positionName = "Manager";
            p.salary = 1000;

            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.name = "John";
            e.position = p;

            ResultJson r = new ResultJson();
            r.name = e.name;
            r.positionName = e.position.positionName;
            r.salary = e.position.salary;

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Position position { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public string positionName { get; set; }
        public int salary { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultJson
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string positionName { get; set; }
        public int salary { get; set; }
    }
```

use seperate model for result

Comment: wouldn't recommend it as this solution is very specific and require a model class for every type of result that will be needed

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code with [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library

```
[JsonObject]
public class Employee 
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    string name;
    [JsonProperty("positionName")]
    string positionName;
    [JsonProperty("salary")]
    int salary;
}
```

Use One class instead 2, or realize own parser

Comment: this will not give the result the op asked for

Answer (score -2):

try in this way.
{
    "name": "John",
    "position": 
    [{
    "positionName": "Manager",
    "salary" : 1000
    }]
}

Comment: This won't work. Moreover, I want to both serialize and deserialize.

Comment: try removing "[ ]"(square bracket ). for more you can refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx