# With Json.NET, how can I merge two C# objects that need to be serialized together?

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, json.net

Say I have some classes that I often serialize normally, such as

```
public class A
{
    public A(int x, bool y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    [JsonProperty("x_thing")]
    public int X { get; }

    [JsonProperty("y_thing")]
    public bool Y { get; }
}

public class B
{
    public B(string s)
    {
        S = s;
    }

    [JsonProperty("string_thing")]
    public string S { get; }
}
```

If I want to start here (but pretend `A` and `B` are arbitrary objects):

```
var obj1 = new A(4, true);
var obj2 = new B("hello world");
```

... then how can I idiomatically produce this JSON serialization?

```
{
    "x_thing": 4,
    "y_thing": true,
    "string_thing": "hello world"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two objects during serialization using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811301/merge-two-objects-during-serialization-using-json-net)

Comment: Do you want to merge them as strings?

Comment: @gunr2171 the only generic solution in there involves authoring your own converter, which I just cannot believe is the nicest method

Comment: @Heinzi good thought, but I'd rather convert each to an intermediary object before serialising that - seems far more efficient... currently looking into Json.NET's Linq.JObject for that

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko I mean, necessarily I think I'd need to merge them as abstract objects...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JObject` has a [Merge](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) method:

```
var json1 = JObject.FromObject(obj1);
var json2 = JObject.FromObject(obj2);
json1.Merge(json2);

// json1 now contains the desired result
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQdRYv)

---

If your objects contain properties with the same name, you can use the overload taking a [JsonMergeSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonMergeSettings.htm) object to specify how conflicts should be resolved.

Comment: thank you! I also like that I can just `json1.ToObject<object>()` if I want to keep it as an object for later use/serialization (which I actually do in my case, since this combined object ends up becoming part of an ASP.NET controller response!)